# how to use watin to test Ajax wedsites?

Tags: ajax, watin

//using watin test some ajax sites,when click td,div("appendProdctTreeDiv") will show some response html,but i don't know how to get this div innerhtml and click link whick i wanna;
can give some examples by test “http://www.google.com/ig”？thanks in advance！

------using watin--------
IE ie = new IE(); 
....
ie.Element(Find.ById("tree")).Click();
textbox1.text=ie.Div("appendProdctTreeDiv").innerHtml;// this way is wrong;
...

---

..html code..

<'TD id=tree onclick=showAppendProductTree() noWrap>tab1<'/TD>

....

<'DIV style="WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 96%; OVERFLOW: auto" id=appendProdctTreeDiv loaded="false"><'/DIV>

....

---

function showAppendProductTree(){

```
showTreeTab(3);
```

if(document.getElementById("appendProdctTreeDiv").loaded == "false" ){

```
    var url ="product!changeAppendProduct.do";

var params = "";

var newProductId = document.getElementById("newProductId").value;
    new Ajax.Request(
    url,
    {
        method: 'get',
        parameters: params+"&random="+Math.random(),
        requestHeaders:["Cache-Control","no-cache"],
        onComplete: function(originalRequest){  
        var message = originalRequest.responseText;
        document.getElementById("appendProdctTreeDiv").innerHTML= message;
        document.getElementById("appendProdctTreeDiv").loaded = "true";
                    synAppendTree();
        document.getElementById("waitLoadAppendProd").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("searchDiv").style.display = "block";
            }
    });

}
```

}

function showTreeTab(tabId) {

```
document.getElementById("treeDiv").style.display ="block";

for(var i=1;i<=3;i++){

    if(i==tabId){
        document.getElementById("tree"+i).style.display = "block";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById("tree"+i).style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Im sorry but the English in the description is very poor and don't understand what you are asking...

Answer (score 5):

I think you have several options to wait for the response. Option 1:

- First of all, WatiN by default waits 30 seconds for an element to show up on the page. So if you know the id or text of the link you want to click on I would expect the following code to work:

  ie.Div("appendProdctTreeDiv").Link(Find.ByText("text of the link")).Click();

If it doesn't, here is option 2:

- In the script firing the ajax call, in the oncomplete callback function the loaded attribute of the div gets set to true (is false in the html you included). You can use this in a wait until call and then get the innerhtml or click the link you want to click:

  ie.Div("appendProdctTreeDiv").WaitUntil("loaded", "true");

HTH,
Jeroen

Comment: thinks,i had finish it by "watiuntil" yesterday.your option 2 is right for my situation.

Comment: Could you mark this answer as being the accepted one so others will know this is the prevered solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the asynchronous AJAX call is still in progress when you are getting the innerHtml.

> > ie.Element(Find.ById("tree")).Click();
> >
> > textbox1.text=ie.Div("appendProdctTreeDiv").innerHtml;// this way is wrong;

Try something like this to see if you end up with expected results.  This is the not so great way to do it, but checking is easy.

> > ie.Element(Find.ById("tree")).Click();
> >
> > System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);    //Waits for 5 seconds; make more than 5 seconds if your async call takes longer.
> >
> > textbox1.text=ie.Div("appendProdctTreeDiv").innerHtml;// this way is wrong;

If the site is using ASP.NET, to determine if the page is in an async call you can eval the following javascript.

> > Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack()

Call like

> > bool isInAsync = bool.Parse(ie.Eval("Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().get_isInAsyncPostBack()"));

However, google.com/ig does using MS AJAX so I cannot come up with a working example using the above javascript.

Example using wait and google.com/ig's translation gadget.  Put in a different word into TypeText on each run or clear your cache.
            ie.GoTo("www.google.com/ig");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);  //Wait for page gadgets to load
            Console.WriteLine(ie.Frame("remote_iframe_10").Div("dict_content").InnerHtml);

```
        ie.Frame("remote_iframe_10").Form("dictForm").TextField("dictQuery").TypeText("bajar");
        ie.Frame("remote_iframe_10").Form("dictForm").Buttons[0].Click();

        Console.WriteLine(ie.Frame("remote_iframe_10").Div("dict_content").InnerHtml);
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);  //Wait for gadget to finish here.
        Console.WriteLine(ie.Frame("remote_iframe_10").Div("dict_content").InnerHtml);
```

Comment: thinks a lot,i had solved it,just use ie.Div("appendProdctTreeDiv").WaitUntil("loaded", "true");